# In C what does [foo] = bar mean?

Tags: c

I was just reading [some code](http://git.suckless.org/st/tree/st.c#n488) in the [st terminal emulator](http://git.suckless.org/st/tree/st.c#n488) and came across this syntax:

```
static void (*handler[LASTEvent])(XEvent *) = {
    [KeyPress] = kpress,
    [ClientMessage] = cmessage,
    /* Removed some lines for brevity ... */
};
```

I have never seen this syntax in C and I am not even sure what to google for. I have a rough idea what it does (defining handler as an array of function pointers), but I would like to understand this syntax better. It seems to be valid at least in C99, but I am looking for some more details why this is correct, how exactly it works and maybe a pointer to the C standard where this syntax is defined.

Comment: If I had to venture a guess, it appears to be some indexed array initialization.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is initializing an array of function pointers with enum indexes. See [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/15/array-initialization-with-enum-indices-in-c-but-not-c).

As mentioned in the comments below uses [Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

This short example should show how it can be used.

```
enum indexes {ZERO, ONE, TWO, FOUR=4};
int array[5] = {[FOUR]=1, [TWO]=9};

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d, ", array[i]);
```

This prints out

```
0, 0, 9, 0, 1,
```

Comment: @Ianoxx asked for a pointer to the C standard. "Designated initializers" are described in paragraph 6.7.8 clause 17 . The specific example is EXAMPLE 9